# Why are my map annotations all passing the same results to my view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, annotations, mapkit

Each annotation is passing the same location to EventView instead of their individual coordinates. Each coordinate should have a separate page with unique information. Sorry if the code is put in wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(locationManager.region) ,showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: annotations){annotation in MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinates){
           if annotation.event == true{
                 Button(){
                     readyToEvent = true
                 }label: {
                     Text("E")
                     .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                     .foregroundColor(.white)
                     .background(.blue)
                 }
                     .sheet(isPresented: $readyToEvent){EventView(eventLoc: annotation.coordinates)}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .accentColor(Color.red)
                    .onAppear(perform: locationManager.requestLoc)
                    .onAppear(perform: fetchLocations)
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question but don't do this `if annotation.event == true` just use `if annotation.event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, where you use the more appropriate `.sheet(item: ...)`. Place it outside
the `Map(coordinateRegion: ...)`, and use a `@State var selected: YourAnnotationType?`
as the selected annotation to pass to the `EventView` obtained from the `Button`.

```
@State var selected: YourAnnotationType?  // <--- here
// ...
 
var body: some View {
    //....
    Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(locationManager.region) ,showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: annotations) { annotation in

        MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinates) {
            if annotation.event {
                Button{
                    selected = annotation  // <--- here
                } label: {
                    Text("E")
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(item: $selected){ annotation in  // <--- here
        EventView(eventLoc: annotation.coordinates)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Map")
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```